# Dreamweaver change file in dual screen view

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, dreamweaver

I do my coding in dreamweaver CS5 in code view only. I recently just discovered the "dual screen" workspace in which I got rid of all the clutter so that it is just the main workspace and the secondary workspace in the corner.

However, the secondary view only displays the source code. I want to have the source code in the main workspace and then have a different file, such as a CSS or Js file in the secondary. Is there a way to switch between files in dual screen mode or is the source code the default for the second screen and cannot be changed? I've spent 30 min searching for answers and found nothing.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: dreamweaver workspace]

I want the small screen to have the Js file and then obviously I can choose any file in the main one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see from you screen grab is you are using Code Inspector - it displays your HTML in a floating window so you see your working pages in their full glory rather than have them cut in half as in Split View.

Have you tried Dreamweaver's Code Split View, please read [link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3294892)

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. I saw that option in the view tab on the menu bar but i though it was the same as the split tab for showing code and design. didnt even think to try it. thanks!